# SSIS 2012 join table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, join, ssis-2012

I need to take non-normalized data and create normalized tables.

I can't figure out how to get the detail ID to insert into the join table (StoreAddress.AddressID in the example below).

If I were doing this as a stored proc in T-SQL within a loop I would use @@IDENTITY after inserting the row in Address to get the key and then use it to insert into StoreAddress.   I can't figure out how to do using transforms in SSIS 2012.

Using Store and Address as an example.

The input data looks like:

```
Store, Type, Address1, City, State
1, P, 123 Main, Central, PA
1, M, 123 Second, Central, PA   
2, P, 123 Third, Pokono, NY
2, M, 123 Third, Pokono, NY
```

The destination tables are:
Store (already populated in different data flow)

```
StoreID, StoreName, StoreNumber
9878, Main street, 1
561, Mountain View, 2
```

AddressType (already populated in different data flow)

```
AddressTypeID, Code, Description
1, P, Physical
2, M, Mailing
3, O, Other
```

Address

```
AddressID, Addr1, City, State
721, 123 Main, Central, PA
843, 123 Second, Central, PA
1098, 123 Third, Pokono, NY
```

StoreAddress

```
StoreID, AddressID, AddressTypeID
9878, 721, 1
9878, 843, 2
561, 1098, 1
561, 1098, 2
```

I think this should be a fairly common transformation and there is a best practice to accomplish it in SSIS.

Thanks for thinking of my question!

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by inserting the different Addresses:

```
INSERT dbo.Address (Addr1, City, State)
SELECT DISTINCT Address1, City, State
FROM input;
```

(Maybe have WHERE NOT EXISTS if you have values already in there)

Then use lookups to fetch the values for your StoreAddress table.

```
INSERT dbo.StoreAddress (StoreId, AddressId, AddressTypeID)
SELECT
  (SELECT s.StoreId from dbo.Store AS s
    WHERE s.StoreNumber = i.Store)
, (SELECT a.AddressId FROM dbo.Address AS a
    WHERE a.Addr1 = i.Address1
    AND a.City = i.City
    AND a.State = i.State)
, (SELECT at.AddressTypeId 
   FROM dbo.AddressType AS at
   WHERE at.Code = i.Type)
FROM input AS i;
```

Using sub-queries like this is just like using joins, but safer because you won't impact the number of rows in `input`.

In pure SSIS, do a Data Flow Task to get your address table sorted, using a Sort on the address columns only, with distinct turned on. Then you can do another Data Flow Task with three Lookup transformations to get the IDs like in the query that I wrote above.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer!  This is certainly a more Set based SQL approach than my code based loop.  However it doesn't seem to leverage the SSIS transform framework.  I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if anyone else responds with SSIS specific approach.

Comment: Nice!  I'll try both and see which performs better!

Comment: This approach fails because there are multiple stores with the same address.  Therefore the lookup of the AddressID fails because it matches multiple rows.

Comment: @TimothyVogel Your lookup is not against your input, but against your Address table, which should only have each address once, with no mention of store.